# Using Mocha in Rails to test form_for path generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocha.js

Using the resource routes, you can do things like url_for(@apple) to get a url to that particular resources "show" method. However, in testing, using Mocha to mock up my objects, I'm having trouble generating the appropriate path to the resource.

E.g. Consider this example of how url_for routes:

```
@apple.id # => 4
url_for(@apple) #=> domain.com/apples/4
```

This is equivalent to the more verbose:

```
url_for(:controller => 'apples', :id => 4, :method => :show)
```

In attempting to test my views, I use Mocha to mock up my objects.

```
Apple.stubs(:color => 'red') # returns a MochaExpectation, rather than an instance of Apple.
```

So in my test:

```
assigns[:apple] = @apple = Apple.stubs(:color => 'red')
url_for(@apple) #=> raises undefined method `mocha_expectation_path'
```

How can I get approach this? It seems either stubs needs to return an Apple < ActiveRecord::Base or url_for needs to understand what to do with a mocha_expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) incorrectly.

If you want an instance of a traditional mocha object :-

```
@apple = stub('apple', :colour => 'red')
```

If you want to stub specific methods on a real object :-

```
@apple = Apple.new
@apple.stubs(:colour => 'red')
```